# Get the string representation of an object without loading the object into memory

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pickle, repr

Is there a way to get the string representation of an object on disk without loading the object into memory? I thought of calling `repr()` on the file object returned from calling `open()` on the object but that returns the class/mode of the file object [per documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

```
import os
import pickle
import tempfile
import datetime
from copy import copy

class Model:
    def __init__(self, identifier):
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.creation_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0} created on {1}'.format(self.identifier, self.creation_date)

identifier = 'identifier'
model1 = Model(identifier)
model2 = copy(model1)

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as directory:
    with open(os.path.join(directory, identifier), 'wb') as f:
        # persist model and delete from RAM
        pickle.dump(model2, f)
        del model2

    with open(os.path.join(directory, identifier), 'rb') as f:
        print('is model stale: {}'.format(repr(model1) != repr(f)))
        print('Disk model: {}'.format(repr(f)))
        print('RAM model: {}'.format(repr(model1)))
```

I'd like to return the string representation of `model2` (i.e. `identifier created on <creation_date>`) without actually loading `model2` into memory.

Do share another workaround you may have used to accomplish a similar purpose.

Thanks.

- MacOS
- Python 3.6.4

Comment: No there isn't any way.

Comment: How could that possibly work? The `__repr__` method needs to acces properties of the object, where is it supposed to get them from if the object isn't loaded into memory?

Comment: Couldn't you just embed the `identifier/creation_date` info in the file-name?

Comment: Good thought @ekhumoro. In our process, we'd like to avoid having the timestamp on the model name itself.

Comment: @sedeh. Or use a non-compressed archive (e.g. [tar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#module-tarfile)) which contains the pickle plus a small file containing the relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

If you serialize your object as JSON rather than binary .pickle, you can manipulate or filter the text directly without deserializing it.  See [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable) for some nice examples (particularly the jsonpickle and .toJSON answers).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an lazy pickle loader many years ago [here](https://github.com/wavii/listy-django-cache/blob/master/listy/on_demand_pickle.py). You could pickle a `((id, creation_date), model)` and then just deserialize that first tuple.